# Bitemporal Database Design Question

Tags: database, database-design, architecture

I am designing a database that needs to store transaction time and valid time, and I am struggling with how to effectively store the data and whether or not to fully time-normalize attributes. For instance I have a table Client that has the following attributes: ID, Name, ClientType (e.g. corporation), RelationshipType (e.g. client, prospect), RelationshipStatus (e.g. Active, Inactive, Closed). ClientType, RelationshipType, and RelationshipStatus are time varying fields.  Performance is a concern as this information will link to large datasets from legacy systems.  At the same time the database structure needs to be easily maintainable and modifiable. 
I am planning on splitting out audit trail and point-in-time history into separate tables, but I’m struggling with how to best do this.

Some ideas I have:

1)Three tables: Client, ClientHist, and ClientAudit. Client will contain the current state. ClientHist will contain any previously valid states, and ClientAudit will be for auditing purposes. For ease of discussion, let’s forget about ClientAudit and assume the user never makes a data entry mistake. Doing it this way, I have two ways I can update the data. First, I could always require the user to provide an effective date and save a record out to ClientHist, which would result in a record being written to ClientHist each time a field is changed. Alternatively, I could only require the user to provide an effective date when one of the time varying attributes (i.e. ClientType, RelationshipType, RelationshipStatus) changes. This would result in a record being written to ClientHist only when a time varying attribute is changed.

2) I could split out the time varying attributes into one or more tables.  If I go this route, do I put all three in one table or create two tables (one for RelationshipType and RelationshipStatus and one for ClientType).  Creating multiple tables for time varying attributes does significantly increase the complexity of the database design.   Each table will have associated audit tables as well.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot depends (or so I think) on how frequently the time-sensitive data will be changed. If changes are infrequent, then I'd go with (1), but if changes happen a lot and not necessarily to all the time-sensitive values at once, then (2) might be more efficient--but I'd want to think that over very carefully first, since it would be hard to manage and maintain.

I like the idea of requiring users to enter effective daes, because this could serve to reduce just how much detail you are saving--for example, however many changes they make today, it only produces that one History row that comes into effect tomorrow (though the audit table might get pretty big). But can you actually get users to enter what is somewhat abstract data?

Comment: Thanks for the replay! The ClientType will change rarely, if ever. But in the event that it does we need to know what it was at a given point. The client relationship type and status will change more frequently, but not that often. Another idea is to just split off RelationshipType and RelationshipStatus into seperate tables. This would be slightly easier to maintain.

Comment: Yes, I agree about getting the users to enter the dates.  But they will have no choice since they are the one's wanting to to track this data historically. The question that I have is how to make the data entry intuitive. They are going to have to distingusih between updating incorrect information and actual data changes. Using whether or not the effective date changed, but that is not 100% since they could just be correcting a bad effective date.

Comment: To make it more intuitive, could you design things such that whenever users enter significant data, they know/are told that the change will come into effect at the end of the day (i.e. starts up next day)? Maybe at the start of the next business week (Monday)? If the effective date is always calculated the same way, they don't have to worry about it. And if they enter subsequent changes before their prior changes become "active", then (by definition?) the earlier and now overwritten entries would be "incorrect information".

Comment: Yes, I think that is an excellent idea. Thanks so much for taking the time to respond!

Comment: In Stack Overflow, if you agree with or approve of a reply, whether to your own or to other's questions, remember to "upvote" them.

Comment: @PhilipKelley He would but he couldn't because he doesn't have the enough reputation (15) to upvote you.

Answer (score 0):

you might want to try a single Client table with 4 date columns to handle the 2 temporal dimensions. 
Something like (client_id, ..., valid_dt_start, valid_dt_end, audit_dt_start, audit_dt_end).
This design is very simple to work with and I would try and see how ot scales before going with somethin more complicated.